# Not getting expected return value from function

Tags: javascript, arrays, request, return

So, I am getting a csv file from a url. I am then turning each row into an array of objects.

```js
const translation = {
    '緯度': 'latitude',
    '経度': 'longitude',
    '測定局コード': 'Measuring station code',
    '測定局名称': 'Bureau name',
    '所在地': 'location',
    '測定局種別': 'Measuring station type',
    '問い合わせ先': 'Contact information',
    '都道府県コード': 'Prefecture code'
}
const csv_url = 'https://soramame.env.go.jp/data/map/kyokuNoudo/2022/10/06/01.csv';

// request the csv file from csv_url and create an array of stations objects

var stations = [];
request(csv_url, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err || res.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        const rows = body.split('\n');
        const headers = rows[0].split(',');
        for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) { // start at 1 to skip headers
            let station = {}; // create a new station object for each row
            const row = rows[i].split(','); // split the row into columns
            for (let j = 0; j < row.length; j++) { // loop through each column
                station[translation[headers[j]]] = row[j]; // add the value to the station object by using the header as the key
            }
            var data = stations.push(station)
            console.log(stations)
            return data;
        }
    }
}
);
```

That all works fine... when I `console.log(stations)` inside of the function I get the expected output.

```
{
  latitude: '43.123333',
  longitude: '141.245000',
  'Measuring station code': '01107030',
  'Bureau name': '手稲',
  location: '札幌市手稲区前田２－１２',
  'Measuring station type': '一般局',
  'Contact information': '札幌市',
  'Prefecture code': '01'
}
{
  latitude: '43.123333',
  longitude: '141.245000',
  'Measuring station code': '01107030',
  'Bureau name': '手稲',
  location: '札幌市手稲区前田２－１２',
  'Measuring station type': '一般局',
  'Contact information': '札幌市',
  'Prefecture code': '01'
}
{
  latitude: '43.123333',
  longitude: '141.245000',
  'Measuring station code': '01107030',
  'Bureau name': '手稲',
  location: '札幌市手稲区前田２－１２',
  'Measuring station type': '一般局',
  'Contact information': '札幌市',
  'Prefecture code': '01'
}
```

however when I `console.log(stations)` *outside* of the function I get an empty list. I am declaring 'stations' outside of the function, and the function is appending the objects to the array. Why isn't it working and what can I do to solve this? also, when I return 'data' that doesn't return the array from. 'stations' either.

Comment: `var data = stations.push(station); return data;` <-- Why are you doing this? The `push` method simply returns the updated `length` of the array, which isn't useful here. Also, using `return` inside a `for` loop means it won't continue iterating....

Answer (score 0):

The call to `request` is asynchronous.
Therefore, calling `console.log(stations)` in the line immediately after your call to `request` will print the empty list while your `request` continues to run in the background.
It prints too quickly - before the `stations` list has been populated.

Whatever you need to do with `stations`, you either need to do it in a success callback passed to `request`, or you need to `await` the request.

As [Dai says above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73993070/not-getting-expected-return-value-from-function/73993134#comment130647637_73993070), `push` is actually mutating the `stations` array.

I am not sure what implementation of `request` you are using but it may return a value so you may be able to do something like `const response = await request(...)` (this could work in conjunction with fixing the error Dai pointed out - one way would be to move the declaration of `stations` inside the `else` clause, and then return `stations` at the end of the `else` clause).

If you can't `await` it, you will need to pass a callback that performs the `push`es to `stations` defined as is.